# Use any Random Function in anchor lang

Tags: anchor, rust, metaplex, anchor-lang, candy-machine-v2

`Rand` lib is supported in `rust` but not supported in `anchor lang`. I want to generate a random number lets say between a range of 0-10. Is there is a way I can do in anchor lang. Or alternatively, if there is a way I could use candy machine random NFT functionality with `url` as I want to use random numbers to be passed in url.

Code snippet:

```
 let random_number = 0; // this is supposed to be a random number let say b/w [0-10]
 let path = "http://abc.com";
 let new_uri = format!("{}{}{}", path, random_number, ".json");

            invoke(
                &create_metadata_accounts_v2(
                    ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.key(),
                    ctx.accounts.metadata.key(),
                    ctx.accounts.mint.key(),
                    ctx.accounts.mint_authority.key(),
                    ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
                    ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
                    num_title,
                    symbol,
                    new_uri,
                    Some(creator),
                    1,
                    true,
                    false,
                    None,
                    None,
                ),
                account_info.as_slice(),
            )?;
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that you can can use rust functionality on anchor lang. have you tried implementing rand in you code?

Comment: yes, I did that it is supported in rust but when using anchor lang it is not supported as the randomness of a function can be guessed which can be a security issue as well as you can run out of compute units if the random range is too large.

Comment: duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70693497/how-to-get-random-number-in-solana-on-chain-program/70701389#70701389

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a way that we can simply use timestamps for this.

```
   let clock = Clock::get()?;
   let clock = clock.unix_timestamp % 10; // any number between range 0-10
```

Just make sure the random number range is not too large else you may run out of compute units. In case of a very large range of numbers, you can make this implementation on the admin panel where only a transaction signed by admin wallet can call this function (if security is important).

Comment: This approach can be exploited.

Comment: Can you explain how? I was going to use this option for something monetary.

Answer (score 4):

As defined [here](https://docs.solana.com/developing/on-chain-programs/developing-rust#restrictions) you can’t use random either in **Rust** or in **Anchor** if you want to generate a random number either you create your own number or you can use an oracle like a switchboard for generating a random value.

- If you write your own random function using recent blockhash or timestamps available in the program it's most likely to be exploited.
- So it's better to use an oracle for generating the random number. [Verifiable Randomness On-chain](https://switchboard.xyz/randomness)

## References

- [Switchboard VRF Demo](https://github.com/switchboard-xyz/vrf-demo-walkthrough)
- [Utilize Switchboard's verifiable randomness to simulate a heads or tails coin toss.](https://github.com/switchboard-xyz/vrf-flip)
- [Live demo of Heads or tails coin toss.](https://vrf-demo.switchboard.xyz/)

Comment: We can use random numbers in simple ```Rust``` without ```anchor lang``` using ```rand``` lib.